# After installing AMDGPU Pro I can't log into Ubuntu. How to fix it?

Tags: login, amd-graphics, amdgpu-pro

I've installed AMDGPU-PRO but can't log into Ubuntu 16.04. Everytime I give my password, it take me back to the log in screen. How can I install it. I've tried with --px parameter, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-F1 to switch to a console, then login as normal, then use `sudo apt purge amdgpu-pro`. You could alternatively boot in to recovery mode from the grub boot screen.

Comment: Is there any way to use AMDGPU-Pro?

Comment: Why do you want to? AIUI the are some reasons to use it, perhaps CAD/CAM applications but for normal desktop use and for games the regular drivers are best. I'm using the stable "pkppa" version, others use "oibaf", and "xorg-edgers". If you want -pro then you can check your /var/log/syslog and Xorg.0.log for errors and debug from there.